# jQuery slider - setTimeout crossbrowser glitch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, settimeout

Ok, I tried to create another slider of preloaded images (whatever you wanna call it) with only two directional buttons. Got the animations the way I wanted them and the control idea was from a tutorial.

(Tutorial: [How to Make Auto-Advancing Slideshows](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/01/how-to-make-auto-advancing-slideshows/))

So, I adapted the autoadvance solution to my needs and got everything working OK. But, when I tried to run it in FF (8.0) I got a little problem. After a button click it does everything as it should except the part where the animation continues after the preset 3 seconds time, while IE (8.0) does not have problems (didn't tested in other browsers).

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the necessary code:

Html part:

```
<div id=imgholder1>
    <div id="imgholder2"></div>
</div>
<div id="bwd" class="button"><</div>
<div id="fwd" class="button">></div>
```

jQuery/JavaScript:

```
var traker=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    var numOfImages=4;
    var timeOut = null;

    (function autoAdvance(){
    $('#fwd').trigger('click',[true]);
    timeOut = setTimeout(autoAdvance,3000);     
    })();

    function preload(imgIndex,numImages){
        $("#imgholder1").css('background-image','url("'+imgIndex+'.jpg")');
        $("#imgholder2").hide(0);
        imgIndex < numImages ? imgIndex++ : imgIndex=1
        $("#imgholder2").css('background-image','url("'+imgIndex+'.jpg")');
        traker=imgIndex;
    }
    preload(1,numOfImages);

    function animate(imgIndex,numImages){
        $("#imgholder2").fadeIn("slow",function(){
            preload(imgIndex,numImages);
        });
    }

    $("#fwd").bind("click",function(e,simulated){
        animate(traker,numOfImages);
        if(!simulated){
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
            timeOut = setTimeout(autoAdvance,3000);
        }
    });

    $("#bwd").bind("click",function(){
        var temp=traker-2;
        if(temp == 0){temp=numOfImages;}
        if(temp == -1){temp=numOfImages-1;}
        $("#imgholder2").css('background-image','url("'+temp+'.jpg")');
        animate(temp,numOfImages);
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        timeOut = setTimeout(autoAdvance,3000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fix!

This:

```
(function autoAdvance(){
    $('#fwd').trigger('click',[true]);
    timeOut = setTimeout(autoAdvance,3000);
})();
```

should look like this:

```
function autoAdvance(){
    $('#fwd').trigger('click',[true]);
    timeOut = setTimeout(autoAdvance,3000);     
}
autoAdvance();
```

FF didn't recognize self calling function autoAdvance otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it looks like your `timeout` variable is in the wrong scope - declare it outside of everything so that it is shared between functions:

```
var traker=0;
var timeOut;
```

Personally, I also avoid using reserved method keywords that are close like that, so  use:

```
var tmr;
```

Also, you should use `window.setTimeout` rather than just `setTimeout`

Comment: None of the suggestions work. Thanx anyway for trying. I also read somewhere that would be better to use namespaces to avoid mix up. Sadly, its not of any help here.

Comment: I might suspect the way you detect an auto click - I've handled it differently when doing this sort of thing, setting a global flag (bAutoClick = true). You're setting `simulated` - hey, maybe that's it. Be sure to set `simulated` back to `false` in the `Click` event. Perhaps FF is giving it a higher scope.

Comment: Its the same, no visible effect whatsoever.

Comment: I looked more closely, but don't see anything obvious. Move the simulated flag to just a global boolean and remove it from the function call and parameters. Add some console.log() prints to make sure your code is actually hitting the setTimeout you have in the click event. I suspect that if(!simulated) is not returning the expected result in FF.

Comment: How could I forget FireBug and console.log() so stupid of me. Well I'm not a coder just trying something new and stuff. he he Its getting late here (different time zone) so I'm off to sleep. Thank you for your time and for putting up with me so long Matt. Tomorrow, when I have time, I'll run this with FireBug and see what the logs say and report here. Thanx again and good night.

Comment: Happy New Year Matt. Your idea worked. FireBug was a great help,how could I forget about it. 

Well, to the problem now:

Comment: `autoAdvance is not defined
(?)(e=Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", timeStamp=1325430733959, more...}, simulated=undefined)2d97e~ue.html (line 107)
handle(event=Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", timeStamp=1325430733959, more...})jquery.js (line 3001)
eventHandle(e=click clientX=32, clientY=191)jquery.js (line 2635)
[Break On This Error]  

tmr = window.setTimeout(autoAdvance,3000);`

Comment: It seams FF doesn't recognize the so called auto executing function autoAdvance, so I just made it a regular function and added a standard call inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});` and that fixed it. Thanx for everything.